# Three.js Map Texture to irregular Geometry (UW-Coordinates)

Tags: three.js

I have a problem with mapping a texture in THREE.js which is possibly related to creating custom UV-Coordinates as extensive search indicates.

The following picture shows a geometry which was created from THREE.BoxGeometry by manipulating the lower vertices of the box. The texture on the side looks stretched (although this is correct I guess). 
[picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbOdw.png)

Is there a way of "projecting" the texture onto the side, e.g. by creating custom uv-coordinates to look like in the second (photoshopped) picture?
[picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1QjO.png)

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to remap your vertices manually to perform what is called a "box mapping" or a "triplanar mapping".

Here is an example I threw together: https://codesandbox.io/s/qxk8xvnrvj

It creates a cube with some subdivisions.. perturbs those vertices if they are on top... and then does the iterations through the faces uvs and vertices to remap each faces UVs with a box mapping, by finding the dominant axis the face normal points along... and then using the other 2 axis' as the U and V axis for unwrapping.

Comment: Glad I could help! ;)

https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

fwiw, I appreciate the thanks comment, so ignore that part. ;)